# how to optimize loop queries with laravel eloquent

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

i'm trying to fetch categories , subcategories and products in "tree view" from my database.
i'm new in laravel and I dont know how can I write this action better with eloquent methods.
I have 2 table : Products and Categories
each product has category_id that is foreign key of categories table

here is my code:

```
    $categories = Category::with('products')->where('id', $category->id)->get()->toArray();
    foreach ($categories as $key => $value) {

        $categories[$key]['children'] = Category::with('products')->where('parent_id', $value['id'])->get()->toArray();
    }
```

this is my result and its fine

"result": [

```
    {
        "id": 2,
        "name": "Root 2",
        "parent_id": null,
        "products": [],
        "children": [
            {
                "id": 4,
                "name": "First child of Root 2",
                "parent_id": 2,
                "products": [
                    {
                        "id": 5,
                        "category_id": 4,
                        "name": "مهسا واثقی",
                        "description": "Aut eum et rerum dolorum blanditiis et itaque ipsum. Reiciendis consectetur magni est veritatis qui. Eos veniam quo aspernatur exercitationem vel incidunt. Rem aut sunt ab exercitationem.",
                        "price": "58.00",
                        "type": "video",
                        "disabled": 0,
                        "created_at": "2019-02-03 22:38:37",
                        "updated_at": "2019-02-03 22:38:37"
                    },
                ]
            },
            {
                "id": 5,
                "name": "Second child of Root 2",
                "parent_id": 2,
                "products": []
            },
            {
                "id": 6,
                "name": "Third child of Root 2",
                "parent_id": 2,
                "products": []
            }
        ]
    }
],
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try with a recursive relationship, just like this:

```
public function childCategoriesRecursive()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Category::class, 'id', 'parent_id')->with('childCategoriesRecursive');
}
```

When you load this new relation, Laravel will automatically select all your category hierarchy. So then your code should be something like:

```
    $categories = Category::with(['childCategoriesRecursive', 'products', 'childCategoriesRecursive.products'])->where('id', $category->id)->get()->toArray();
```

Now, there's no need to loop all your categories.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

You can use "whereIn" instead of the query in a loop.

```
$categories = Category::with('products')->where('id', $category->id)->get()->toArray();
$parentCategory = $categories->pluck('id');
$categoriesObject = Category::with('products')->whereIn('parent_id', $parentCategory)->get()->toArray();
foreach($categoriesObject as $key => $value){
 $childObject[$value->paernt_id][] = $value;
}
foreach($categories as $key => $value){
  $categories[$key]['child'] = isset($childObject[$value->id]) ? $childObject[$value->id] : [];
}
```

Comment: thanks but it does not retun name and products of parent category

Answer (score 0):

You can do with the **recursive function** by this:

```
$categories = Category::with('products')->where('id', $category->id)->get()->toArray();

$categoriesWithChild = $this->GenerateCategoryArray($categories);
dd($categoriesWithChild);
```

Add this function in your **controller**:

```
function GenerateCategoryArray($arr, $parent = null)
{
    $pages = Array();
    foreach($arr as $page)
    {
       if($page['parent_id'] == $parent)
       {
           $page['child'] = isset($page['child']) ? $page['child'] : $this->GenerateCategoryArray($arr, $page['id']);
           $pages[] = $page;
        }
     }
      return $pages;
}
```